# Many sleep process in mariadb when using Mariadb Galera Cluster

Tags: mariadb, galera

I setup mariadb galera cluster, When i check a node, there are many sleep process.
Picture: http://prntscr.com/f3ktpr
How to resolve problem?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have a client that has some form of "connection pooling", and is set to have a few dozen such.  And you have run queries 40,000 seconds ago.  Those started up separate pool threads.

Bottom line:  Not a problem.

Comment: I don't run the queries, they are running by "system user" (If i run then it will shown "root" user). I think the queries are running by Galera Cluster, and Does it affect the my system? Thank you!

Comment: "Sleep" queries are not a problem.  I can't think why Galera would be causing it.